# TypeError: Cannot read property '_t' of undefined on component instance, when the component is generater with Vue.extended

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-i18n

Hello I am trying to use the vue-18i-n in order to translate the application, the code when I use this is the component that I'll create after call to API of the following way:

Create component on api.vue

```
esponseJSON.forEach(element => {
            let card = Vue.extend(card)
            let instance = new card({
              propsData: {
                cha: element
              }
            })
            instance.$mount()
            this.$refs.deck.appendChild(instance.$el)
```

And in the card.vue compontent I have the following code:

```
<h5 class="card-title">{{$t('card_title')}}</h5>
```

But I get the following error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '_t' of
>   undefined"

How can I print the translate?

Thanks

Comment: This `let card = Vue.extend(card)` isn't going to work.

Answer (score 1):

add  `instance.$root = this.$root;` before `instance.$mount();`